# How to join fetch LAZY field of key of Map-ElementCollection?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have my Document-entity. It has some fields, and this field:

```
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @CollectionTable(name = "document_external_dispatches",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "document_id"))
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "external_dispatch_id")
    @Column(name = "is_active")
    private Map<ExternalDispatch, Boolean> externalDispatches;
```

My ExternalDispact-entity has LAZY field Company:

```
    @NotNull(message = "Company must not be empty")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
    private Company company;
```

So i want to find Document by ID with externalDispatches map. And i want that my External Dispatches will get with field Company.
I tried to write this query, but this does not work:

```
@Query("select d from Document d left join fetch d.externalDispatches externals join fetch key(externals).company where d.id=:id")
```

Please help me to write Query for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently impossible, it also seems the JPA specification didn't handle this. Here for reference: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11433

Instead of doing fetch joins though, you could use DTOs for which you could write a proper query. Something like this:

```
select d.id, d.name, ex.id, c.id, c.name 
from Document d 
left join d.externalDispatches e 
left join ExternalDispatch ex on ex.id = key(e).id 
left join ex.company c 
where d.id = :id
```

Having said that, this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your query could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(Document.class)
public interface DocumentDto {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    String getName();
    @Mapping("this")
    Set<ExternalDispatchDto> getExternalDispatches();

    @EntityView(Document.class)
    interface ExternalDispatchDto {
        @Mapping("KEY(externalDispatches).company")
        CompanyDto getCompany();
        @Mapping("externalDispatches")
        Boolean getDispatch();
    }
    @EntityView(Company.class)
    interface CompanyDto {
        @IdMapping
        Long getId();
        String getName();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`DocumentDto d = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, DocumentDto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

Comment: Thank you for advice!